# Proof that $(n^4)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ diverges to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I've been googling this, but couldn't find similar proofs.

I have to prove that the sequence $\{n^4\}$ diverges to infinity and I was wondering if my proof is valid ( especially the first line of the proof that's bold.)

Proof.

Note that $n^4 \ge  n^3\geq n^2 \geq n.$ (Since $n$ is natural).

Let $N > L$ for any $L > 0$.

If $n > N$, we have $n^4 \ge n^3 \ge n² \ge n > N > L$.

By definition, the sequence diverges to infinity. Q.E.D.

Comment: By what definition does that mean the sequence diverges? Diverges usually means it doesn't converge to a real number, so usually there is an $\epsilon$ involved.

Comment: It's definitely the right approach, though.

Comment: I'm not sure about the line "$N>L$ for any $L>0$". It seems like $N$ is the largest natural number to exist.

Comment: In short: when $n$ obviously diverges to infinity and $n^4\ge n$ for all $n$ what is the only possibility for $n^4$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is valid, though it will benefit from phrasing that's more precise. I assume you are using the definition

> $(x_n)$ diverges to infinity if $\forall L>0$ there exists $N$ such that $x_n>L$ for all $n>N$.

If so, then I recommend rephrasing

> Let $N>L$ for any $L>0$.

so that it reads more clearly:

> Let $L>0$ be given. Take any integer $N>L$.

Comment: Yes I was using the definition you wrote. Thank you for the rephrasing! It looks clearer

Answer (score 1):

Your proof looks roughly correct, but could do with a couple of extra details.

For example, it should be clear that you're attempting a proof by contradiction and so you should start with "Suppose $(n^4)$ is convergent, and its limit is $L$" so it's clear where $L$ comes from later in the proof.

Comment: I was using the definition of diverge that grand_chat quoted. 
However, I'll try to solve it using proof by contradiction. Thanks

Comment: They're fundamentally the same proof, but it's still good to be clear about what your symbols represent one way or another.